# How to set DNS from command line on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, desktop-environments

I'm trying to set a DNS server on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. So far this is what I have.

In `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` this is the content:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Since everything is commented, that means DNS servers are not set here.

In `/etc/resolve.conf`, this is the content:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search *domain*.com
```

In `/etc/netplan/**-netconf-**.yaml`, this is the content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: yes
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - ***********
          - ***********
          - ***********
```

Just for security, I placed *********** over the IP addresses, but they are not what is shown when I run `systemd-resolve --status` or `resolvectl status`:

```
Link 2 (ens160)
      Current Scopes: DNS           
DefaultRoute setting: yes           
       LLMNR setting: yes           
MulticastDNS setting: no            
  DNSOverTLS setting: no            
      DNSSEC setting: no            
    DNSSEC supported: no            
  Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8   
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8  
                      8.8.4.4    
                      8.8.2.2  
          DNS Domain: **domain**.com
```

The DNS Servers and DNS Domain are not exactly what I've posted for security measures. But I'm just showing that its different from what's in `/etc/netplan/**-netconf-**.yaml`

And finally to my point, the file `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`
DOES have the DNS servers that are shown in the `systemd-resolve --status`. This is the content of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.2.2
search **domain**.com
```

BUT! When I'm editing this file and changing the DNS servers addresses, it does not change when running `systemd-resolve --status`. And when I run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`, it just reverts back to the original.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.2.2
search **domain**.com
```

I do not know where else the DNS is obtained from in order to revert back to it after resetting systemd-resolved .

Comment: Hi - sorry, I wasn't totally clear from the intro to your question, are you trying to set a specific DNS server address on your Ubuntu device? Have you tried using the graphical interface via the Settings app?

Comment: @johnandmegh Hi John, Yes I'm trying to set a specific dns server addresses on Ubuntu devices as part of an automated script process thats why I do not want to use the GUI.

Comment: @mpboden Hi, Thanks for your response!
i have desktop distro installed, and i checked the NetworkManager, can't find anything that have to do with DNS...

Answer (score 0):

With a Desktop installation of Ubuntu 20.04, networking is managed by *Network Manager* and not *systemd-networkd*. As a result, your current Netplan YAML configuration file will not take effect.

Typically, network configuration, and specifically DNS, is defined within the GUI. But since you've indicated that you want to set DNS servers via the command line, you can do this with `nmcli`.

Also note that by default, Ubuntu uses a local stub resolver to cache DNS queries for faster resolution. Even though you want to define specific uplink DNS servers, I still recommend that you take advantage of the stub resolver.

You've indicated that you edited `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf/`. Don't do this. It clearly states in the file:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
```

---

1. Start by returning `/etc/resolv.conf` as a symlink pointing to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` with the following command.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. Next, return your Netplan YAML file to default.

   - Delete your current Netplan YAML file:

     ```
     sudo rm /etc/netplan/**-netconf-**.yaml
     ```
   - Create a new Netplan YAML file with the editor of your choice: `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

     ```
     # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
     network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager
     ```
3. Set specific DNS servers for your connection. Let's use a VM I created as an example.

   - Show your connections:

     ```
     $ nmcli connection
     NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
     Wired connection 1  882bdeaa-c11e-36cb-bef4-b89fff1d9aa0  ethernet  enp0s3
     ```

     In this example, the connection is named '*Wired connection 1*'. So if yours is different, adjust accordingly moving forward.
   - Let's ignore any DNS servers pushed to you from your DHCP server:

     ```
     nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
     ```
   - Add a DNS server to your connection:

     ```
     nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
     ```
   - If you want to add an additional DNS server:

     ```
     nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' +ipv4.dns 1.1.1.1
     ```
   - If you want to set multiple DNS servers at once instead of using multiple commands:

     ```
     nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1"
     ```
   - To set a search domain:

     ```
     nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.dns-search localdomain
     ```
   - When complete with your modifications, reload your connection:

     ```
     sudo nmcli connection reload
     ```
   - Finally, restart Network Manager:

     ```
     sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
     ```

At this point, your DNS servers and search domain will be set as your uplink DNS servers and search domain for your connection. To see this, run `resolvectl`. Notice the DNS servers and search domain set for Link 2 at the bottom. This is for device `enp0s3`, which matches the device for our connection we modified with `nmcli`.

```
$ resolvectl
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8    
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8    
                      1.1.1.1    
          DNS Domain: ~.         
                      localdomain
```

The end result of this is that a configuration file is created by `nmcli` in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. Take a look at the file created by the above commands:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'Wired connection 1.nmconnection' 
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=882bdeaa-c11e-36cb-bef4-b89fff1d9aa0
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=enp0s3
permissions=
timestamp=1709607559

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns=8.8.8.8;1.1.1.1;
dns-search=localdomain;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

You'll also notice that `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` has been updated with your DNS servers and search domain:

```
$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
search localdomain
```

---

For more information:

- Ubuntu website:

  [nmcli manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html)

  [Network Manager](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager)
- Arch Linux website:

  [Network Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager)

  [Description and Settings for nmcli](https://man.archlinux.org/man/nm-settings.5)